# set different colors for columns in highstock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to set different color for columns (volume) based on whether the stock moved up or down.  So I added 'color' when filling the 'volume' array:

http://jsfiddle.net/vU5Zg/

```
volume.push({
    'x': data[i][0], // the date
    'y':data[i][5] // the volume
});

if (i != 0 && data[i][4] < data[i-1][4]) {
    volume[i].color = '#DE32AE';
}
```

But all the columns turns back to black when I clicked '6m' button. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding dataGrouping: { enabled: false }, in the plotOptions.